# What is this spring known as?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, mechanical, springs

Could anyone tell me what the spring part of [this](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/products/8180599/) component is called please so I can source something similar?

[image]

Comment: Might not have a name. I wouldn't be surprised if that was bent in a custom die specifically for that product. Do you need one? or a thousand?

Comment: Probably just need one.

Comment: @Pyy Get a wire bender and a vise and lots of music wire. Keep doing it until you get a good one. I'm guessing you're going to be pretty good by the time you get a good one.

Comment: It might also be a torsion spring with bent ends (I can't see what is under the aluminum but you can't do the coil on a typical wire bender): https://www.grainger.ca/en/product/SPRING-375-OD-90-DEG-TORSION-6PK/p/WWG3HPD1

Comment: it may be a version of a leaf spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The torsion spring with bent ends seems like a good fit for my application. Thanks for helping identify this :)